# AngularJS ng-click function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

please help me, I would like to access a function using ng-click like this :

```
             <tr ng-repeat="data in listtalentapegawai">
                <td>            
                    {{data.nip}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.nama}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.tgl_grade_terakhir}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem1_2012}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem2_2012}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem1_2013}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem2_2013}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem1_2014}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem2_2014}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{data.sem1_2015}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ui-sref=".modal"  ng-click="showAlert(data.nip)">Simulasi</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

data.nip come from `ng-repeat="data in listtalentapegawai"`

and this is the state I wrote :

```
 .state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
            url: '/modal',
            views:{
                "modal": {
                    templateUrl : 'public/js/modal.html',
                    controller: 'simulate'
                }
            }
         })

angular.module('routerApp').controller('simulate', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.showAlert = function (provider) {
       //console.log('clicked signin ' + provider); 
       $scope.nip = provider;
   }

   $scope.showAlert();
}])
```

The problem  is provider doesn't have value. Actually I woul like to pass the data.nip from showAlert(data.nip) to a modal dialog

Comment: can you provide a link in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Since you are using `ui-sref`, do you want to change state and show alert dialog?

Comment: I am new to angular, actually i would like to open modal and put data.nip value inside modal, but first I would like to learn how to call a function from ng-click. I have tried to delete the ui-sref, but the result still nothing appear

Comment: what is data.nip and where is it defined?

Comment: data.nip come from ng-repeat="data in listtalentapegawai"

Comment: it won't work because `ng-click` is registered in the parent controller, not the controller of teh child state `.modal`

Comment: I have updated the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

try this in your states:

```
.state('masterpegawai.alltalenta.modal', {
    url: '/modal',
    templateUrl : '/your/path/to/html/file.html',
    controller : 'MyPageController'
 })
```

And create controller separately:

```
angular.module('appModule', []).controller('MyPageController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.showAlert = function (provider) {
       alert('clicked signin ' + provider); 
   }

   $scope.showAlert();
}])
```

Comment: the modal pop up but the alert doesn't

Comment: @AriefGrando It should popup if you call the function. Updated code in my answer, try it now.

Comment: Hi xSaber, provider undefined